# Web video playback rate

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to, through javascript code, change the playback rate of a web video to more than 16x speed, eg. 20? Because after using:
`document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 20;`
an error:
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'playbackRate' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided playback rate (20) is not in the supported playback range.` occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/media/html_media_element.cc;l=170?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2Fchromium%2Fsrc%2Fthird_party%2Fblink%2Frenderer%2Fcore%2Fhtml%2Fmedia%2Fhtml_media_element.cc

I think most of the major browsers still cap it at 16.

You best bet is to change the actual file to reflect the desired speed.